# Joining Table/DataFrames with common Column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

```
df1 = ['Date_Time',
    'Temp_1',
    'Latitude',
    'N_S',
    'Longitude',
    'E_W']

df2 = ['Date_Time',
    'Year',
    'Month',
    'Day',
    'Hour',
    'Minute',
    'Seconds']
```

As You can see both DataFrames have `Date_Time` as a common column. I want to Join these two DataFrames by matching `Date_Time`.

My current code is: `df.join(df2, on='Date_Time')`, but this is giving an error.

Comment: Both the Dataframes have different number of rows..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are looking for a [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge):

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Date_Time')
```

*The keywords are the same as for `join`, but `join` uses only the index, see ["Database-style DataFrame joining/merging"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).*

Here's a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 7, 8],[4, 9, 9]], columns=[0, 3, 4])

In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3

In [5]: df2
Out[5]: 
   0  3  4
0  1  7  8
1  4  9  9

In [6]: df1.merge(df2, on=0)
Out[6]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  7  8

In [7]: df1.merge(df2, on=0, how='outer')
Out[7]: 
   0   1   2  3  4
0  1   2   3  7  8
1  4 NaN NaN  9  9
```

If you try and join on a column you get an error:

```
In [8]: df1.join(df2, on=0)
# error!
Exception: columns overlap: array([0], dtype=int64)
```

*See ["Joining key columns on an index"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index)*.

Comment: It is giving me an error when i run merge:- UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 268: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @RahulBhatia can you include the output of `df1.to_dict()` and `df2.to_dict()` in your question? That's a strange error, and sounds like a string encoding issue...

Comment: yes i can...This is the format of the Date : 13/11/2012  7:32:32 AM

Comment: can the 'AM' cause this problem

Comment: it shouldn't do, because that is in ascii (and you error is complaining about not being ascii), try converting the date to datetime (e.g. by using `pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])`), it could be from another column... :S

Comment: what is pd ? I think the whole column is read as a string and not a Date-Time....please help how to do it ?

Comment: `pd` is pandas (see above `import pandas as pd`), you might have imported it differently. `df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])` will convert it to datetime. But a unicode error is more likely to be the wrong `encoding` when using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), maybe try `latin-1` (or find out if it is something different).